# Symfony Fatal Error __construct() must be an instance of MyBundle\FileUploader

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, doctrine-orm

I have literally followed this tutorial on uploading a file in Symfony but am getting an error which I have sat looking at for about an hour.

The full error:

```
FatalThrowableError in FileListener.php line 21:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to MyBundle\FileListener::__construct() 
must be an instance of MyBundle\FileUploader, string given, called in 
/dev/shm/appname/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 830
```

The 2 classes in question is a fileuploader class and a doctrine file listener class. The error arises in the fileListener to what I think it being caused as I am not creating an object of fileuploader anywhere, but the tutorial dosn't:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

Code for fileupload:

```
namespace MyBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class FileUploader
{
private $targetDir;

public function __construct($targetDir)
{
    $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
}

public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

    $file->move($this->targetDir, $fileName);

    return $fileName;
}

public function getTargetDir()
{
    return $this->targetDir;
}
```

}

Code for file listener:

```
namespace MyBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use MyBundle\Entity\MainMedia;
use MyBundle\FileUploader;

class FileListener
{
private $uploader;

public function __construct(FileUploader $uploader)
{
    $this->uploader = $uploader;
}

public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    $this->uploadFile($entity);
}

public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    $this->uploadFile($entity);
}

private function uploadFile($entity)
{
    if (!$entity instanceof MainMedia) {
        return;
    }

    $file = $entity->getFile();

    // only upload new files
    if (!$file instanceof UploadedFile) {
        return;
    }

    $fileName = $this->uploader->upload($file);
    $entity->setFile($fileName);
}
```

}

I have also set the YAML services:

```
   file_uploader:
  class: MyBundle\FileUploader
  arguments: ['%file_directory%']


  file_listener:
  class: MyBundle\FileListener
  arguments: ['file_uploader']
  tags:
       - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
       - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

and the parameter in config for the directory:

```
  file_directory: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads'
```

Anyway hope you can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your yaml file you write `arguments: ['file_uploader']`. This passes the string "file_uploader" to the constructor of your `FileListener`. What you actually want is to pass the service that is referenced by the name "file_uploader". You do this by prepending an @-sign, like so:

`arguments: ["@file_uploader"]`.